# How to write a function to chain elements together in ProtractorJS/Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am trying to build a function that can accept an array of tag name, by passing in the array of tag names, such as `['span', 'input', 'strong']` I want it to return a chain to search for the elements.  For example, I want to find...

```
element(by.tagName('span'))
  .element(by.tagName('input'))
  .element(by.tagName('strong'));
```

By using my a function like...

```
  public static getNestedElements = (arrayOfElementTags) => {
    const temporaryElementArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfElementTags.length; i++ ) {
      temporaryElementArr.push(element(by.tagName(arrayOfElementTags[i])));
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < temporaryElementArr.length; j++) {
      if (j !== temporaryElementArr.length) {
        temporaryElementArr[j] = temporaryElementArr[j] + '.';
      }
    }
    return temporaryElementArr
  };
```

The above function obviously sucks and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element(by.tagName('span')).element(by.tagName('input')).element(by.tagName('strong'));
// equivalent to element(by.css('span input strong'))
```

Therefor you can join all tags with space to generate a css selector. And use the css selector to find element. As following done.

```
public static getNestedElements = (arrayOfElementTags) => {
  return element(by.css(arrayOfElementTags.join(' ')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep your logic simple instead of using a function.

```
element(by.tagName('span')).element(by.tagName('input')).element(by.tagName('strong'));
//It is a simple way to get the chained element provided by protractor api 
documentation.
```

Creating a function is cumbersome and it won't give you desired results all the time.